# what is the default name of home page for asp 3.5?

Tags: asp.net

My web server just changed to asp 3.5. My site isn't finding the main domain. It shows a 500 error. But it does show inner pages. e.g. mysite.com & mysite.com/?var=thing etc all show a 500 error but mysite.com/inner.asp & mysite.com/inner.asp?var=thing display the page fine. I don't understand the problem. My home page is named home.asp.

Answer (score 0):

The default page created when you create a new website is 
default.aspx.

Using IIS, you would go to your website, and select it. Then under the IIS settings, you have Default Document setting.  For me, this is where I would specify what to use if no page is requested.  Not sure how you are hosting, but maybe this helps. Good luck.

[DefaultDocumentSettingInIIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nYao.png)

Comment: Default.aspx does not load.